# Загрузка изображений на Wordpress-сайт WP REST api в Delphi 10.4 через RESTClient или INDY или любые другие

Tags: wordpress, delphi, rest, indy

**Не получается залить изображение на мой сайт Wordpess через REST api в Delphi 10.4.** У меня почти сразу получилось опубликовать пост через REST api (в REST Debugger и непосредственно в программе), но без картинок в этом нет смысла.

Самый последний вариант кода с компонентами RESTClient:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var jpgFoto: TMemoryStream;
begin
  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Username := 'логин';
  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Password := 'пароль';

  RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'wp/v2/media';
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://*.ru/wp-json';

  RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="00s.jpg"');//Пробовал разные написания варианты оформление из интернета
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');//пробовал разные варианты, например multipart или воообще без этой строчки

  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('data-binary', 'D:\Europe\00s.jpg');//есть ли в этом смысл?
  RESTRequest1.Params[0].Kind := pkGETorPOST;

  jpgFoto := TMemoryStream.Create;
  jpgFoto.LoadFromFile('D:\Europe\00s.jpg');
  RESTRequest1.AddBody(jpgFoto, TRESTContentType.ctIMAGE_JPEG);
  jpgFoto.Position := 0;

  try
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
  except
    memo1.Text := RESTResponse1.Content;
  end;


  jpgFoto.Free;

end;
```

Выдаёт ошибку или

> {"code":"rest_upload_invalid_disposition","message":"Неверное значение
> Content-Disposition. Content-Disposition должно быть в формате
> `attachment; filename="image.png"` или
> похожем.","data":{"status":400}}

или

> {"code":"rest_upload_no_content_disposition","message":"Заголовок
> Content-Disposition не указан.","data":{"status":400}}

в зависимости от настроек которые и спользовал в Header RESTRequest

Я нашел вариант [решения на международной версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817903/how-to-upload-a-media-item-to-wordpress-from-delphi-rio-app-using-trestclient) , который помог как минимум одному человеку: перейти в INDY на компонент idHTTP (к сожалению без подробностей). Как я не бился у меня не получилось авторизоваться через метод Basic Authentication. Я задал параметры в IDHTTP.Request.Username и IDHTTP.Request.Password, но получил ответ от Wordpress - 403 Forbidden. И непонятно в каком формате заполнять параметры, в JSON или просто parameter = value

только начал разбираться в REST и завяз уже на очень много часов. Прошу не оставить в беде и помочь загрузить изображения в Wordpress api REST компонентами delphi REST или Indy или любой другой рабочий способ, буду ооочень благодарен

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий код

```
var
   Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
 Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
 Params.AddFormField('content-type','image/jpeg');
 Params.AddFile('file', 'c:\images\sdsd.jpg', '');//поле с файлом называется file
 idhttp2.Request.Accept := 'application/json; charset= UTF-8';
 idhttp2.Request.Authentication := TIdBasicAuthentication.Create;
 idhttp2.Request.Authentication.Username:= 'имя пользователя';
 idhttp2.Request.Authentication.Password := 'пароль';
 idhttp2.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;

 idhttp2.Request.ContentDisposition := 'form-data; filename="anyname.jpg"';//
 idhttp2.Request.ContentType := 'application/json; charset= UTF-8';

 try
     idhttp2.Post('htts://сайт/wp-json/wp/v2/media/', Params);
 except
   memo1.Text :=  idhttp2.ResponseText;
 end;

end;
```